adding class to texBox1.Tag
I want to add few custom properties to controls.
so i am trying this.
 textBox1.Tag = new Customer();

its perfect. at runtime, I can see the tag has an object customer.
but in design time I want to give value to Customer Properties. But c# could not find any property.
available on runtime but not in design time.
textBox1.Tag.CustomerCode
textBox1.Tag.CustomerName
//if i do like 

textBox1.Tag = new Customer  {
                                customerCode = "001"
                             };

than compiler works. but i need to update the value after initializing. and I could not find way to update it.
if its not working then can anyone suggest me the another idea to add custom properties to textbox which available in coding time.

Tag is an object, so you'd need to cast it to your target class before you can use the target class's properties. However, I'm not sure why you'd want to do what you're doing. This seems like an X/Y problem.

@gunr2171 i assigned a object to class. but how to update that object properties after initialization. that's my question. OR can you elaborate your point with some piece of code?

If you want TextBox with custom property - wrap it under single UserControl. To be able to manipulate custom properties through Designer - take a look at DesignerAttribute or EditorAttribute or so, but it's not supposed to be used to assign new instances of objects as you do with Tag. Your question lacks short description how TextBox and Customer are related (or should be) and because of that looks unclear/not focused.

@auditive Textbox. Customer property have information about the Textbox Record.
one of property is ControlSource which I want to use dynamically bind textbox with class and binding source. I hope you understand what I want to achieve.

Don't put the answer in the question.  Post it as an answer.
